# Explanation of a VBA code (Macro) regarding returning multiple values in a single cell

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a Macro for excel I found online to create a 'myvlookup' function which allows to lookup all instances of a number in a range and return a specified corresponding column; multiple instances if necessary. I've gotten the macro and respective myvlookup to work for my needs but I'd like an explanation of the logic/meanings behind how this code works. Code is below and any information would be helpful. P.S I'm code illiterate, so don't assume I know anything lol. Thanks!

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String

xResult = ""

For Each rng In pWorkRng

    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next

MYVLOOKUP = xResult

End Function
```

Comment: one way to learn what the code is doing is to [step through line-by-line](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) and watch what it does.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation is given via comments inline:

```
' Declare a custom function called MyVLOOKUP and specify 
' that 3 arguments must be passed to it when it is invoked.
' These arguments can be named any legal name, but the values
' that eventually get passed in must match the declarations for
' each argument (String, Range, Long Integer)
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)

  ' Declare a variable that will represent a cell/range
  Dim rng As Range

  ' Declare a variable that will hold the function's overal result
  Dim xResult As String

  ' Initialize the result variable to an empty string
  xResult = ""

  ' Loop through each cell/range in the range that was passed into the
  ' function and stored under the argument name "pWorkRng". The "rng"
  ' variable just acts as a temporary identifier that represents each
  ' cell/range that is being looped over - one at a time.
  For Each rng In pWorkRng

    ' Check the cell/range that the loop is currently looping over
    ' to see if it matches the supplied argument ("pValue") that was
    ' passed in when the function was called.
    If rng = pValue Then
        ' If the cell/range is a match for the input argument
        ' set the function's return value variable to itself,
        ' concatenated with an asterisk character and the value 
        ' of the cell/range that is one column to the left of
        ' the cell/range being looped over. ("pIndex" is supplied
        ' to the function as a way to indicate what column the
        ' lookup is to be done in).
        xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If

  ' Loop to the next cell/range
  Next

  ' Now that the loop is finished, have the function return its
  ' final value, which will either be an empty string ("") if no
  ' cells/ranges match the input or the value of the cells that 
  ' are one column to the left of the found ranges.
  MYVLOOKUP = xResult

End Function
```

Now, having explained the code, I should point out that this:

```
  If rng = pValue Then
```

Should be written more explicitly as this:

```
  If rng.Value = pValue Then
```

And this:

```
  xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
```

Should be:

```
  xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1).Value
```

Because without the explicit `.Value` property accessor, the code reads as if you want to compare a Range object to a value, which are not the same thing. You want to compare the VALUE of a Range object against a value. The code does do this as you have it, but it is getting the `.Value` only because no property is specified and `.Value` is the default property. Being explicit is better.

Comment: Thanks Scott! This is a perfect explanation

Comment: @user2972193 No problem. Don't forget to mark as the answer if you are happy.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
    'the "Function" word define that is that, a Function not s SubRutine, then name is MYVLOOKUP
    'and need some parameters: pValue As String, pWorkRng As cell/Range, pIndex As Long
    'and String is a string of characters, A range is just that and a Lond stores values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

    'Dim declares variables and allocates storage space.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    'Here you have two variables rng and xResult

    xResult = "" 'here you set the xResulta var as empty var
                 'also you can do this: xResult = Empty is exactly the same
    'Loops!
    'You read this this way
    'For each rng (that is a range that is a cells inside a couple of cells/bigger range)inside pWorkRng you will do this
    'then if inside the pWorkRng the is 100 cells, the loop will run 100 time (if is no errors)
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng = pValue Then 'would be better |rng.value = pValue| for better reading
        'if the value of rng (one cell from pWorkRng) is equal to the value of pValue then do this:
            xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) 'here would be better |rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1).value|
            'store inside xResult this = the value of xResult with this string " * " and the value of
            'rng with an columns offset of pIndex -1 (not in rows)
            'note that the & (ampersand) is the operator to concatenate strings, then if you have two strings
            'x = "abc"
            'y = "def"
            'and you do this:
            'x = x & y
            'inside x you will get "abcdef", because when you asign the value of a variable, you will erase any other
            'previous value and write the new values
            'rng.offset(0,pIndex-1) says:
            'rng.offset(row,columns)
            'rng.offset(same row as rng | 0, col)
            'Imagine rng address is G5, then rng.offset(2,1) address will be H7 because you say, send me the address of the cells
            'plus 2 rows and plus 1 column, then if you send a negative number this way rng.offset(-2,1) you will get H3,
            'then that is why in rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) you will get the same row and the column indicated (inside the var pIndex)
            'less one.
            'And because this happends inside a loo, that runs n times, do the validation (the if statement)
            'you will store values concatenated with the previous valus inside xResult
        End If
    Next 'this word say: go to the next cell, then when is finish just continue
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult
    'here you send the string of inside xResult to the function, that is, you will see that string in your cell
End Function
```

Comment: Your explanation of `xResult = xResult & " * " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)` is incorrect.

Comment: Right! Thanks! I fixed

Comment: Thank you!! You all have been of great help.